# Please show how to calculate the probability for outcomes of this Battle Royale scenario.

Tags: probability, game-theory

Please note: This is not about an isolated problem at all, but rather a way of quantifying and visualizing an obfuscated and confusing game theory related model in an easy to grasp manner. For that I require the assistance of math experts in probability, which I am not. If you are interested in helping ,please show how to calculate the probability of results for the following game scenario.

I hope someone finds this interesting. I appreciate your help, Thank you!

*Edit: Forum members have enlightened me to the complexity of the scenario and I appreciate all of the comments.  I have made some edits in response to the comments..thank you.*

Problem:
A Battle Royale/last person standing elimination match tournament.
Matches are comprised of 64 players per match, randomly populated.
Players compete in 1 on 1 encounters throughout the match. 1 player is eliminated in each encounter until there is 1 player left in the match- the last person standing.
*A forum member asked how the match ups are decided.* maybe it should be 64 players per match for simplicity sake with random matching of pairs for 5?? rounds.

At the end of each match points are awarded to the top 3 finishers as follows: 1st place =15 points, 2nd place = 8 points, 3rd thru 4th place = 4 points, and 5th thru 64th place =zero points.

There are two types of player:
Player type L and Player type H.
Player type L has no advantage over any other Player type L in an encounter and the outcome is 50/50 or a coin toss as to who wins.  However, Player L has a disadvantage in an encounter with Player H. Player type H has a 20x advantage in winning an encounter with Player L.

Player H has no advantage in an encounter with another Player type H, where the outcome is a 50/50 coin toss as to who wins. However, Player type H has a 20x advantage versus any Player type L in an encounter.

Each Player will play exactly 150 matches in the season.
A leader board reports every player’s accumulated points total score for the season.
There are 4,700,000 type L players
There are 300,000 type H players.

Without adding any other variables or complexity to the scenario above, what is the probability of the following expressed in 1 out of X  and or other terms:

That a type L player would finish the season in the top 500 ranks of points accumulated (out of 5,000,000)?
That the number 1 rank will be a type H?
That the number 500 rank will be a type H?
That the number 1 rank will be a type L?

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

*Edit: This discussion has been productive and I realized that I needed to tweak the scenario a bit to better reflect the key elements of the real world situation. Comparing independent L and H distributions is interesting but as you noted L and H types are competing together in the same matches.   In my tweaked scenario H players make up about 6 percent of the total population. Also the advantage was way to low, so I adjusted it to 20x.
For the sake of simplifying a ballpark estimate, maybe the starting point is to calculate the probability of H and L obtaining points through either a first or second place win in a single typical (“mean”) match.  And then find a way to adjust for the probable deviations from the typical match in 150 matches.

What causes the results of a match to deviate from the “mean” other than the occurrence of no H player present in the match? How likely is it to have a match with no H player present? This seems like a way to come up with some ballpark probabilities for H or L appearing on the Leaderboard in the top 500, or the probability for H or L taking 1st place.*

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: This is not a homework problem.  Having read the stated purpose of Stack Exchange to offer "answers to question without chit chat" I posted this specific game theory related question to the mathematics forum seeking an answer to the specific question.  The context is clearly stated as a Battle Royale game scenario with a specific set of conditions for which I kindly reached out to the forum for an answer.  I cannot give you a formula I tried because I do not even know where to start.

Comment: Ultimately this is not about an isolated problem at all, but rather a way of simplifying and visualizing an obfuscated and confusing game theory related model in an easy to grasp manner.  For that I require the assistance of math experts in probability, which I am not. If I provided more unnecessary detail it might distract from the specific calculations that are sought.

Comment: This seems consistent with Stack Exchange's overall stated mission as a no nonsense straightforward resource. I hope that a math expert will find the probability calculation for the model to be interesting. I don't know if this is a challenging question or an easy one , but I home some math expert will enjoy flexing a bit and give a response.  Thank you very much.

Comment: You're asking volunteers to give a lot of their time and effort to solve a large complicated problem, without giving any evidence that you have tried to solve it yourself, or even why others would be interested in solving it.

Comment: How are players out of the 50 per match chosen for an encounter?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for you reply.  I did not know that this is large and complex problem.  However I am not a math expert. I can tell you I have spent a lot of time on the game problem itself and have expressed the essence of the situation in the question, but it requires math skills I do not possess in order to be able to compute the probability which will help people visualize the model.  I can give credit to the good people at the Stackexchange math forum for the computation if that is desired.  Never imagined this was a big ask I thought maybe some math pro could do it on a cocktail napkin. lol

Comment: Hello Christian, Thank you for your question.  The players are randomly chosen or distributed.  Thank you for your interest and help.

Comment: Oh for the encounter, assumea series of turns in which each player is matched with an opponent. Excellent question did not think of that . Thank you.

Comment: With some unmatched players skipping a turn. Any way to simplify that is fine should not impact the fairly obvious outcome. Just trying to express an order of magnitude for the probability of H vs L ending up on the leaderboard. Thanks

Comment: This problem is not likely to be solved in an exact closed form. Instead, I suggest that you run a simulation (assuming you have sufficicient programming skills).

Comment: Or, I guess 64 players per match...See you math people are brilliant! Thanks!

Comment: I think this is a reasonable question! And MSE is, after all, a site where mathematicians can volunteer to provide their expertise to answer questions of people who do not have sufficient mathematical expertise to answer them themselves.

Comment: Thanks for all of your comments and help.  So I revised the scenario to 64 players per match, successively paired up for 5 iterations or rounds?

Comment: I think this fits better as a programmng project than a math question for this forum.

Comment: There is no third place if you start with 64 players and pair them up simultaneously.

Comment: Well, I can see the volume of computation might be large here unless some simplification can be made without computing every single iteration.  Total layman thoughts here: there is a distribution of H players in the matches and the chances of at least one H player in a match is probably about 1 in 5.  If an H player is present in the match that player has a about a 64/64 chance of 1st place earning 15 points. Or if two H player are present about 64/64 for either 1st earning 15 or 2nd place earning 8 points.  My idea is that the top 500 players will all have about 2,250 points each.

Comment: For the L player the chances of 1st place with no H player in the match is 1/64.  With an H player in the match the chances are 1/64 x 1/10? about zero..lol.. So the H players should have a extremely high probability of comprising virtually all of the top 500 and the odds of an L player in 1st place would be staggeringly exponentially low to the negative what power? maybe it is possible to simplify things like this without a program to run every iteration?

Comment: Hi Christian! LoL...too much fun...well I see how the details are tricky trying to simplify things.  I could eliminate the third place prize I guess. Just trying to put an order of magnitude on how likely it is or not for type H players to be in the top 500 vs L players and some streamlined model that is easier to do. Or would third place be a coin toss between the two losers of the second to last round? Appreciate you pointing all of this out.  Helping to refine it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*This is not a full answer due to lack of time on my part to work out the details (so don't accept it), but this is an outline on how to get one.*

#### First step

First, we only observe the outcome of a fixed player. Say that there are $N\in\mathbb N$ players (in your case, $N=30000000$). Number the players in arbitrary order from $1$ to $N$ and fix some $k\in\{1,\dots ,N\}$. The probability of winning in a given game for player $k$ depends only whether he himself is H or L, and on the number of H or L players in that game. Say that the player plays $g\in\mathbb N$ games in total (in your case, $g=150$). Let $B_1^{(k)},\dots, B_g^{(k)}$ denote  the points this player receives in games $1$ through $g$, respectively. The total number of points that player $k$ has at the end is $T^{(k)}_g \overset{\text{Def.}}=B_1^{(k)}+\dots+B_g^{(k)}$. From the modeling assumptions, the $B_1,\dots, B_g$ are independent and identically distributed. Furthermore, they only take finitely many values (in your case, for example, there are $4$ possible outcomes: One can get $0$, $4$, $8$ or $15$ points.)

From the Berry-Esseen estimates (see for example [1; Satz 15.51] for the formal statement, you may also find references using a search engine), if $(B_j^{(k)})_{j\in\mathbb N}$ is a sequence of iid real random variables satisfying $B_1^{(k)}\in L^3$ and $\mathsf V(B_1^{(k)})>0$, we have, with $T^{(k)}_g \overset{\text{Def.}}=B_1^{(k)}+\dots+B_g^{(k)}$, (and $\Phi(x)\overset{\text{Def.}}=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^x\exp(-y^2/2)\,\mathrm dy$ denoting the CDF of the standard normal distribution)

$$\sup_{x\in\mathbb R}\left\lvert\mathsf P\left(\frac{T_g^{(k)}-\mathsf E(T_g^{(k)})}{\mathsf V(T_g^{(k)})}\le x\right)-\Phi(x)\right\rvert\le\frac{0.6\mathsf E(\lvert B_1^{(k)}\rvert^3)}{\mathsf V(B_1^{(k)})^{\frac 32}},$$

for all $g\in\mathbb N$.

Coming back to our case: Since $B_1^{(k)}$ takes finitely many values, it is clearly $L^3$. And it is also clear that $\mathsf V(B_1^{(k)})>0$.

Therefore, for $g$ large enough, Berry-Esseen gives that the CDF of $T_g^{(k)}$ is, "close" to the CDF of a normal distribution $\mathcal N(\mathsf E(T_g^{(k)}), \mathsf V(T_g^{(k)}))$.

#### Second step

You have to determine $\mathsf E(T_g^{(k)})$ and $\mathsf V(T_g^{(k)})$. Note that these two quantities only depend on whether player $k$ is of type H or type L. To determine $\mathsf E(T_g^{(k)})$ and $\mathsf V(T_g^{(k)})$, I recommend to first answer the following question ("the big question"): "What is the probability that a player of type L/H gets first/second/third/fourth place in a game of $64$ (or more, generally, $n$) players such that $k$ players other than the player himself are of H type?"

Denote by $h$ the total number of H players (in this case $h=29900000$) and let $l$ be the total number of L players (in this case $l=100000$).

Let $N^{(k)}$ denote the number of H-players in the first game of player $k$, where player $k$ is not counted should he be a H-player. Then, by the modeling assumption, $N^{(k)}$ is a random variable with hypergeometric distribution with population size $h+l$ and $h$ "success states" as well as $l$ "non-success states" and $63$ draws.

From the law of total expectation, we then get

$$\mathsf E(B_1^{(k)})=\sum_{j=0}^{63}\mathsf E(B_1^{(k)}\vert N^{(k)}=j)\frac{\binom{h}{j}\binom{l}{63-j}}{\binom{h+l}{63}}.$$

Once you answer the big question above (this can be done approximately using simulations and maybe even exactly using combinatorial arguments), you immediately get $\mathsf E(B_1^{(k)}\vert N^{(k)}=j)$, from which you can deduce the value of $\mathsf E(B_1^{(k)})$. Analogously, you can determine $\mathsf V(B_1^{(k)})$.

#### Third step

Without loss of generality we may assume that players $1,\dots, l$ are of L-type and players $l+1,\dots, l+h$ are of H-type.

We therefore have $E_L\overset{\text{Def.}}=\mathsf E(T_g^{(1)}=\dots=\mathsf E(T_g^{(l)})$, as well as $E_H\overset{\text{Def.}}=\mathsf E(T_g^{(l+1)}=\dots=\mathsf E(T_g^{(h)})$ and $V_L\overset{\text{Def.}}=\mathsf V(T_g^{(1)})=\dots=\mathsf V(T_g^{(l)})$, as well as $V_H\overset{\text{Def.}}=\mathsf V(T_g^{(l+1)})=\dots=\mathsf V(T_g^{(h)})$.

From the argument in the first step, the "top 1" (or "top 500") performance of L-type players is just the maximum ("500"-th biggest) of $l$ random variables that are $\mathcal N(E_L, V_L)$-distributed. These random variables are not independent (if one person looses, the other wins), however it seems like a useful approximation to at first assume that these are independent and to do the same for the H-type players.

The maximum of iid normal distributions hcan be tackled analytically, see for example [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/381212/248311) and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3119903/631742), or approximately using Monte-Carlo-type simulations.

---

## References

[1] Achim Klenke, *Wahrscheinlichkeitstheorie*. 3. Auflage. Springer-Verlag Berlin/Heidelberg (2013).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134292/discussion-on-answer-by-maximilian-janisch-please-show-how-to-calculate-the-prob).

Comment: Thanks @TheSimpliFire